# Can someone explain Ripley's proof (1996) of the splitting of categorical variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cart, intuition

[image: copy of proof]

Specifically I am referring to this theorem:

1) Suppose there are two classes. For a categorical feature , order
the levels in increasing $p(1\mid x = x_i)$. Then a split of the form
$\{x_1, ... x_{\ell}\}, \{ x_{\ell+1}, ... , x_L\}$ maximizes the reduction in average impurity.

I am looking for some basic intuition on this proof since I don't understand the mathematics very well. For the entire proof please refer to page 218 in his book which can be found here:
 https://dmitry.ai/uploads/default/original/1X/9dc03a6a9bd420ffcdee1b576ef28ff326555e19.pdf

At a high level, I think I understand that ordering the categories by the proportion of a label (any label) is somehow equivalent to splitting the node to minimize entropy/tree impurity.

Comment: fyi you can use math formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: With just two classes we can regard $i(p)$ as a function of $p1$
only; it remains strictly concave: This means that since there are only two classes, $p0 = 1-p1$, so it is only a function of $p1$.